# Not able to build AudioKit AnalogSynthX example

Tags: swift4, audiokit

I've updated to AudioKit 4.0.4 and now trying to build the AnalogSynthX iOS example.  The build fails with this error:

```
The file “Pods-AnalogSynthX.debug.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

I am certainly no expert on CocoaPods but I do have gem and pod installed in my /usr/bin.

I did notice in the AnalogSynthX workspace at the bottom of the project navigator a grayed-out "Pods.xcodeproj" with a path set to **AudioKit-4.0.4/Examples/iOS/AnalogSynthX/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj** however there is no such directory in the AudioKit-4.0.4/ package and I do not see such a directory at the git repository.

Any idea on how to resolve this build issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
cd Examples/iOS/AnalogSynthX; pod install;
```

from your bash shell and you should be in business.

Comment: Thanks, Aure!  That should be in the README.md file, shouldn't it?

Comment: Agreed: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/c093fbe37bcf421073101973e9423404aa7c4b03

Comment: At the moment Audiobus is throwing the error "AudioKit/Examples/iOS/Audiobus/Audiobus.swift:120:61: Use of unresolved identifier 'ABPortTypeAudioSender'"